# Regular expression so that only 'a','A','p' and 'P' can be entered as input

Tags: java, regex

Can anyone please tell me regular expression so that only 'a','A','p' and 'P' can be entered as input and at a time only one of those character should be entered?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: was one of those ps supposed to be capitalized?

Comment: how many of them? mixed together or all the same?

Comment: ya sorry one of those p should be capital.

Comment: Oh sorry i forgot to mention that at a time only one of those character should be entered.

Comment: then you'll want to go with the version that has the `^` and `$`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a simple one: `[aApP]`

Does that work for you?

You might have to add language-specific start & end line symbols, e.g. `^[aApP]$` if you want to check that the entire input consists only of that one character.

Comment: Plus one for being a faster typist than I.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you want either upper or lowercase p:

[aApP]

Answer (score 4):

`^[aApP]{1}$` will match a single 'a', 'A', 'p', or 'P'.
`^[aApP]+$` will match one or more 'a', 'A', 'p', or 'P'.

Comment: I'm not sure you need the `{1}`...

Also, don't forget to enclose your regexes in backticks ` so they will show up as `code`

Comment: You're right about the {1}, but it doesn't hurt. Thanks for the tip about the backticks. I'm a long time reader/first time contributer to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

`[aApP]` if you only want to match a single character.

`^[aApP]+$` to match `aa`, `PaP`, but not `ab`.